# HTML Video tag not finding file

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, html5-video

Using Django, trying to pull a video from a model.

I appear to be pulling the correct file path but the video isn't being located.
Have tried adding the full system directory from hard drive rather than just the context folder, hasn't worked out for me either.
Have confirmed that video is in that location.

Should I be using statics for this? Or not because it's located in a model?

**video_output.html**

```
{% extends 'highlights/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  {% for video in highlights %}
          <video width="320" height="240" controls>
            <source src="/media/{{ video.highlight }}" type="video/mp4">
              Your browser does not support the video tag
          </video>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**From views.py**

```
def video_output(request):
    entrydata = Video.objects.last()
    context = {
        'highlights' : Highlight.objects.filter(sourcevideo=entrydata.video_id)
    }
    return render(request, 'highlights/video_output.html', context)
```

**Console output**

```
[04/Apr/2020 11:32:13] "GET /highlights/outputs HTTP/1.1" 200 1960
Not Found: /media/highlights/812.mp4
Not Found: /media/highlights/811.mp4
[04/Apr/2020 11:32:14] "GET /media/highlights/812.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 404 2129
[04/Apr/2020 11:32:14] "GET /media/highlights/811.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 404 2129
Not Found: /media/highlights/814.mp4
Not Found: /media/highlights/813.mp4
[04/Apr/2020 11:32:14] "GET /media/highlights/814.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 404 2129
[04/Apr/2020 11:32:14] "GET /media/highlights/813.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 404 2129
Not Found: /media/highlights/815.mp4
Not Found: /media/highlights/816.mp4
[04/Apr/2020 11:32:14] "GET /media/highlights/815.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 404 2129
[04/Apr/2020 11:32:14] "GET /media/highlights/816.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 404 2129
Not Found: /media/highlights/817.mp4
[04/Apr/2020 11:32:14] "GET /media/highlights/817.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 404 2129
Not Found: /media/highlights/818.mp4
[04/Apr/2020 11:32:14] "GET /media/highlights/818.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 404 2129
Not Found: /media/highlights/819.mp4
[04/Apr/2020 11:32:14] "GET /media/highlights/819.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 404 2129
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
/media/{{ video.highlight }}
```

use

```
{{ video.highlight.url }}
```